# Add method for lists with lombok

Tags: java, lombok

I am currently replacing all my standard POJO's to use Lombok for all the boilerplate code.

So far no problems have occurred, but what i'm missing in the lombok implementation is that there are no generated methods for adding one object to a collection.

Generated Code:

```
private List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

public Object getObject(){..}

public void setObject(List<Object> o){..}
```

What I want extra:

```
public void addObject(Object o) {..}
```

Anyone know if this is getting there soon or if this is impossible?

Comment: So use generated getter - it returns your list - then do add. If you don't like it - you could always wrap in your own class and add methods to it.

Comment: Lombok's feature `@Singular` does exactly what you want.

Comment: Update 2021: I am quite happy with Kotlin, which reduces almost all boilerplate code that Lombok targets. Don't be afraid of the language switch - the compatibility with Java is AFAICT full, and I learned Kotlin it in cca 1 week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) I couldn't find a ticket for it, and, based on the comment on the other answer, I filed one: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1905  So let's see :)

2) For a single collection, it seems that `@Delegate` could do the job:

```
interface CollectionAdders<E> {
  boolean add(E e);
  boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c);
}

interface ListGetters<E> {
  E get(int index);
}

class Foo {
  @Delegate(types={CollectionAdders.class, ListGetters.class})
  List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Generates:

```
Foo#add(E e)
Foo#addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)

Foo#get(int index)
```

See this forum post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/project-lombok/alektPraJ_Q

Comment: That's very interesting, thanks for the update on this issue :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, Roel Spilker dismissed that, pointing out the existence of `@Builder` and `@Singular`, which IMO do not cover the need for shorthand for collections manipulators. You can go there and vote :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me due to the generics, since `@Delegate` doesn't have a way to specify the generic type, so it will default to Object.

Comment: According to the documentation it is not recommended to use the annotation. See https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Delegate

Answer (score 4):

This is surely currently impossible. There's such a proposal, but low priority (or even rejected).

Actually, I can't find it anymore. You may want to try yourself on the [issue list](https://code.google.com/p/projectlombok/issues/list?q=add+type%3DEnhancement).

Now, I stumbled upon this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/project-lombok/alektPraJ_Q) showing an interesting workaround limited to a single variable.

### Bad news

This gets improbably implemented in the near future. There are far too many feature requests to implement and maintain them all (or any non-trivial fraction of them). See [this issue comment](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1905#issuecomment-429958936).

Comment: Full Disclosure: I am one of the Lombok Developers. This is on our list, but I don't think there is an issue about it. But it is pretty high on our own wish list. We are considering different approaches and discuss these regularly ourselves. We'll send a mail to the google group if we have a decent proposal.

Comment: In case anyone finds this. If you don't mind using a builder you can do this using the [@Singular](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder.html#singular) annotation

Comment: @rsavchenko This was exactly my requirement. Thanks you !